# Trouble with Directories in www (Ubuntu 20.04LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, directory

I have a number of domains on my Ubuntu 20.04LTS distro. When I configure the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.conf` for each domain, I set the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/domain.com/public_html`.

As you'd expect, the site files are all in the `public_html` folder and everything works correctly for all my domains **except for one**. Despite it being configured like the rest of the other domains, its site files are actually showing up in `/var/www/html/`. So if I go to https://marcmanley.dev, the domain comes up fine but the site files are not in `/var/www/html/marcmanley.dev/public_html` but rather are in `/var/www/html/`. Any clues as to what's going on here?

If I'm not being clear, this is what the `html` [directory](https://eid.rocks/image-6-11-20.jpeg) looks like:

Here's the `.conf` file of a working domain:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/imammarc.com.conf                            
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin marcmanleydev@gmail.com
  ServerName  imammarc.com
  ServerAlias www.imammarc.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/imammarc.com/public_html
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/imammarc.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/imammarc.com/log/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =imammarc.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.imammarc.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and that of the trouble domain (marcmanley.dev)

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/marcmanley.dev.conf                           
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin marcmanleydev@gmail.com
ServerName marcmanley.dev
ServerAlias www.marcmanley.dev
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/marcmanley.dev/public_html
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/www/html/marcmanley.dev/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/marcmanley.dev/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

***EDIT:*** Additionally:

```
$ ls -lR /etc/apache2/sites-available
total 84
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1516 May 31 23:35 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1569 Jun  1 01:14 000-default-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6338 Apr 13 17:19 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  495 Jun  4 05:38 eid.rocks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  536 Jun  4 05:38 eid.rocks-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  572 Jun  4 05:31 goodbookorganics.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  613 Jun  4 05:31 goodbookorganics.com-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  762 Jun  1 01:10 imammarc.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  729 Jun  1 01:10 imammarc.com-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  516 Jun  4 06:44 islaam.rocks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  557 Jun  4 06:44 islaam.rocks-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  399 Jun  1 02:12 marcmanley.dev.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  523 Jun  4 20:19 marcmanley.me.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  564 Jun  4 20:19 marcmanley.me-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  574 Jun  1 04:25 mynew.faith.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  615 Jun  1 04:25 mynew.faith-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  621 Jun  1 06:57 ramadaan.rocks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  632 Jun  1 06:57 ramadaan.rocks-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  530 Jun  4 05:51 shaykhchef.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  571 Jun  4 05:51 shaykhchef.com-le-ssl.conf
```

and

```
$ ls -lR /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 May 31 23:34 000-default-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun  4 05:20 eid.rocks.conf -> ../sites-available/eid.rocks.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Jun  4 05:38 eid.rocks-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/eid.rocks-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Jun  4 05:30 goodbookorganics.com.conf -> ../sites-available/goodbookorganics.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jun  4 05:31 goodbookorganics.com-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/goodbookorganics.com-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jun  1 00:25 imammarc.com.conf -> ../sites-available/imammarc.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Jun  1 01:10 imammarc.com-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/imammarc.com-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jun  4 05:43 islaam.rocks.conf -> ../sites-available/islaam.rocks.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Jun  4 06:44 islaam.rocks-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/islaam.rocks-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jun  1 02:13 marcmanley.dev.conf -> ../sites-available/marcmanley.dev.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jun  1 02:02 marcmanley.dev.old.conf -> ../sites-available/marcmanley.dev.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jun  4 17:46 marcmanley.me.conf -> ../sites-available/marcmanley.me.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Jun  4 20:19 marcmanley.me-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/marcmanley.me-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jun  1 04:00 mynew.faith.conf -> ../sites-available/mynew.faith.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 Jun  1 04:25 mynew.faith-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/mynew.faith-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jun  1 05:54 ramadaan.rocks.conf -> ../sites-available/ramadaan.rocks.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Jun  1 06:57 ramadaan.rocks-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/ramadaan.rocks-le-ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jun  4 05:51 shaykhchef.com.conf -> ../sites-available/shaykhchef.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Jun  4 05:51 shaykhchef.com-le-ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/shaykhchef.com-le-ssl.conf
```

Comment: Please complete your post with the conf files for one domain that works as expected and for the failing domain + the result of running `ls -lR /etc/apache2/sites-available` and `ls -lR /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the main post to have those in there. You can see above since the number of characters is limited in replies.

Comment: Do you enable/disable with apache commands or do you use linking from `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`? And why two links for `/etc/apache2/sites-available/marcmanley.dev.conf`? (I don't think it matters but why is there two links, one called `marcmanley.dev.conf` and one called `marcmanley.dev.old.conf`)

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure why there's two links - I'm wondering if I made a mistake in setting up the domains. Do you see any reason why the domain marcmanley.dev is not using /var/www/html/marcmanley.dev/public_html as its DocumentRoot but is using /var/www/html/ instead? And how to fix that?

Comment: No, I can't see any reason. The only things that I find disturbing is the mix of relative and absolute links in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and the double links to `/sites-available/marcmanley.dev.conf`. I also don't know how to fix the problem. I would need to see much more code but don't know where to begin.